# OnTouckListener of listview

Tags: android, listview

I am having a `listview`, I want to detect the touch movement up and down. I am using this code. However, when I touch the listview both `UP` & `DOWN` are called. Why? I used log to view up & down movement. What I do with `listview` are both in log.

This is the code:

```
lstviewOrders.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        int action = motionEvent.getAction();

        switch(action)
        {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.w("down:","YES");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.w("UP:","YES");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try my solution? If it was helpful for you please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation of `MotionEvent`

The `ACTION_UP`- [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) - you get when  pressed gesture has finished and the `ACTION_DOWN` - [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) - you get when a pressed gesture has started. Every time when you make pressed gesture you call both.

The `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN` are not the same as swipe up and swipe down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check `SWIPE_UP` and `SWIPE_DOWN` you have to implement your own `OnTouchListener` or you can you this one :

OnSwipeTouchListener.java:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        super.onTouch(view, motionEvent);
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
    public void onSwipeRight() {}
    public void onSwipeLeft() {}
    public void onSwipeTop() {}
    public void onSwipeBottom() {}
}
```

and apply it to your `listView` like this :

```
lstviewOrders.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() { 

    public void onSwipeTop() { 
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    public void onSwipeRight() { 
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    public void onSwipeLeft() { 
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    public void onSwipeBottom() { 
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 

});
```

Comment: i want to detect swipe up and swipe down .